# running docker container with spring boot code

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot

```
Am getting below error when am running my spring boot application in docker container.Any idea why am facing this issue.
```

below is the error that am getting.

am able to run the application without deploying it in docker container.

docker run -p 2000:2000 docker-aws-test

trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'amazonRDS' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.config.AmazonWebserviceClientFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-06-19 14:53:29.152  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'amazonRDS' of type [class com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-06-19 14:53:29.307  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41ba31b0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-06-19 14:53:29.832  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 2000 (http)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier}': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
            at com.miss.equipoptimization.Application.main(Application.java:11) [rulecreation-0.1.0.jar!/:0.1.0]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54) [rulecreation-0.1.0.jar!/:0.1.0]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier}': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            ... 32 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier}': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            ... 34 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1116) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1066) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]        at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.doInvoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:6357) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.invoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:6333) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.executeDescribeDBInstances(AmazonRDSClient.java:2999) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.describeDBInstances(AmazonRDSClient.java:2974) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.getDbInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createDataSourceInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:151) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-1.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.0.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
            ... 44 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:565) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
            at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy44.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
            at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1238) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.319.jar!/:na]
            ... 61 common frames omitted

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier}': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
        at com.miss.equipoptimization.Application.main(Application.java:11)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier}': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier}': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1116)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1066)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.doInvoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:6357)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.invoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:6333)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.executeDescribeDBInstances(AmazonRDSClient.java:2999)
        at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.describeDBInstances(AmazonRDSClient.java:2974)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.getDbInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:167)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createDataSourceInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:151)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:129)
        at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:45)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        at
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to read the whole stack-trace with the formatting you have provided.

I'd say it would appear that your code is having trouble connecting to the RDS instance with the underlying cause being:

> com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0

You may wish to see: [Accessing RDS With SSL - Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472256/accessing-rds-with-ssl-unsupported-record-version-unknown-0-0)

As for why it may work outside of docker and not work when run inside docker, it could be that by default some of the AWS SDK code may be picking up your AWS credentials from your home directory when run on the host machine, e.g. `~/.aws/credentials` for example. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html

When run in docker, I presume you are not mounting this directory or providing the credentials to the application.

Comment: Hi @David Goate my credentials are present in application.properties file.
    FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
    ADd target/rulecreation-0.1.0.jar rulecreation-0.1.0.jar
    EXPOSE 2000
    ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "rulecreation-0.1.0.jar"]
     
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '${db-instance-identifier}': Invocation of init met
    hod failed;
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

Comment: Perhaps it's a difference in the ciphers/SSL/TLS support in the JDK. In your dockerfile you're running from JDK8 on alpine. What OS and version do you use locally on the host where the JAR runs ok? I'd first try to mimic that in the dockerfile with the same java version and OS type if possible.

Comment: Hi @David Goate while running the jar am using windows environment with windows 10.

Comment: what's the output of `java -version` on the host machine?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: I was able to run it successfully n ec2 linus instance,It was the firewall that was causing the issue.